# chef-container + chef-vault

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, docker

I try to run few Chef cookbooks in docker.
[chef-container](https://docs.getchef.com/containers.html) seams to be a good solution for this.
In the cookbook I use credentials which come from encrypted data_bags via [chef-vault](https://docs.getchef.com/chef_vault.html).

Is there already a solution for chef-container in combination with chef-vault?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the annoyance inherent to chef-vault where you have to rehash after creating the node (container) I don't see anything special you would need.

Answer (score -1):

I think that should do. There is a Hashicorp [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) too if you are just looking at alternates. They have both Enterprise and opensource versions.

Vault is a tool for securely accessing secrets and provides a unified interface to any secret, while providing tight access control and recording a detailed audit log.